# Java AST traversal in Sonar in custom rule creation

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to write a new custom Java rule in Sonar using Sonar's java AST api. But I am unable to find any comprehensive api documentation for writing new rules.

I found an example in https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/zipball/master, and implemented it and successfully integrated the given custom rule in Sonar. But I am not really able to proceed further to write new rules due to the lack of proper api or examples. Getting unknown errors while maven-building the plugin.

For example, can anyone help me to create a simple rule like not using System.out.print statements in my code? Any kind of pointers to code examples will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While I, as maintainer of sonarqube java plugin, agree that the documentation of custom rules writing should be improved (and we have this in our TODO list) for code examples of usage of the api you can have a look at the [implemented checks in the java plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/tree/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks)

And as for a rule detecting `System.out.print` statement, [there is already one for that](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/7cddebeb650be4acf56e2befa2ac1c31ed667c49/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/SystemOutOrErrUsageCheck.java#L54-L54) but I would recommend to rely on semantic API (checking symbols and types) for a custom rule rather than relying solely on syntax.

Comment: Hi @benzonica,  I tried to make my custom rule for avoiding System.out from the code base link you provided above . Just changed the Rule key and kept the same structure as I did for integrating earlier. I am getting a error like this, when I am trying to maven build the same project as before to create the custom plugin jar :--             Tests in error:
  AvoidSysoStatementCheckTest.detected:13 ╗ IllegalState At least one issue expected
...
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0               This error is happening for couple of other rules I tried too. What am I missing here?

Comment: This is a failing unit test. Just read the error message in the unit test and fix it. Here it fails because no issue where raised on the source file under test.

Comment: Yup.. solved it.. Thanks @benzonico . However, I have to now implement the following rules: 1. Identifying hardcoded URLs and port nos. in the Java code (including constants) which should be ideally externalized to the properties file  2. Rule to make sure exceptions are getting logged at ERROR level in the catch block.     3. Identifying any logger statements logging credit card or SSN numbers.       Any pointers or help for these would be very much appreciated.